# ActiveRecord Rails: Get records using a condition in the relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is an example: a *User* has many *Cars* and a *Car* belongs to a *User*.

I would like to extract all cars information, but not the cars of some users (this is because I would like to remove me and some colleagues to create correct stats).

I tried this, but without success:

```
Car.where("car.user.name != 'john'")
```

Any idea? Do you have a general rule about getting records with conditions in the relation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the follwing:

```
Car.where('user_id != ?', User.find_by_<name?>('john').id
```

If you have rails 4:

```
Car.where.not(user_id: User.find_by(name: 'john')).id
```

UPDATE:

The solution above will work because you have a foreign key you can query against. More general solution is to perform left join with association table and filter those results. THe following will work regardless of association type (including has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many):

```
Car.includes(:user).where('users.name != ?', 'john')

# rails 4

Car.includes(:user).where.not(users: { name: 'john'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with

```
Car.joins([:user]).where("users.name != 'John'")
```

If you need all the cars information with user information like users.name, then you can have

```
Car.joins([:user]).select('cars.*, users.name AS user_name').where("users.name != 'John'")
```

The above does the thing with a single sql query

```
SELECT cars.*, users.name AS user_name FROM `cars` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `cars`.`user_id` WHERE (users.name != 'John')
```

Comment: This will not return cars without user.

Comment: Yes, I am going to add includes, but you have just specified it in  your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Car.includes(:users).where("users.name NOT IN ('bill','peter','joe') OR cars.user_id IS NULL")
```

It will return all cars that don't have a user name that is Bill, Peter or Joe, and also cars that don't belong to a user !